# If two polynomials over integers are equivalent, are the same polynomial expressions defined over positive integers also equivalent?

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials

It seems obvious that if two polynomials over *integers* are equivalent, then the same two polynomials over *naturals* must also be equivalent, by seeing the polynomials as syntactic expressions. But I can't see how to show this rigorously...

Perhaps, if the two polynomials are equivalent, there's a sequence of algebraic manipulations transforming one into the other. The same sequence will do the same thing for the two polynomials over naturals - provided all the transformations are defined (so no subtractions resulting in negative values).

This came up in the context of using the Schwartz Zippel lemma to show polynomials are equal (by showing their subtraction is always zero). My trouble is showing why this still works when subtraction isn't always defined, as for positive integers, i.e. natural numbers. The issue arose from: [*Is there an efficient algorithm for expression equivalence?*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33113/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-for-expression-equivalence)

Comment: If I am right, it suffices for two polynomials to take the same values over $d+1$ points to be identical.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes I think so, but isn't that derived from $P-Q=0$ (and the Fundamental Theorem of Alegbra)? I'm trying to find the reason that this subtraction is somehow OK, when using naturals... I had a go at answering it here: [How can we prove Schwartz Zippel PIT is applicable to natural polynomials?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/92825)

Comment: Another way to prove is by writing the system of equations defined by the $d+1$ points, which is of the Vandermonde type. Uniqueness of the solution results from a nonzero determinant. When the coefficients of the polynomial are positive, all determinants required for the resolution are positive as well.

Comment: Thanks, thwt sound sounds promising! About what level of math would I need, to understand it?

Comment: Simple algebra.